# better solution for selecting updating many values

Tags: java, mysql, database-design

I want to update some values within a column based on different situations.....
the table has the following details like.....

```
                    Date               date
                    period             int
                    subcode            varchar(3)
                    status_bits        varchar(100)
                    // status bits resemble an information based code based...the data usually stored are  2343211 where each value in digits represent an information.....
```

***Now i've got to update these values based on different dates and periods....
Now considering the `java program`......***

i have stored the details in corresponding variables in java like..

```
                   java.util.Date date[];
                   int period[];
                   String subcode[];

                   // Here for an index i , they share the same values within a row.....
```

If i wanna update it in such a way that that i want to change the 5th letter in a varchar for different dates,periods and subcodes(combined).....
now..i've currently performed like this...

```
     Connection con;
     preparedStatement ps;
     String bitstatus;



     for(i=0; i < noofupdates; i++)
     {
           ps = con.prepareStatement("select status_bits from tablename where Date = ? AND period = ? AND subcode = ? limit 0,1");
           ps.setDate(1,date[i]);
           ps.setInt(2,period[i])'
           ps.setString(3,subcode[i]);

           rs=ps.executeQuery();
           while(rs.next())
           {

                 bitstatus = rs.getString(1);
                 // performed operation to update the bit.....
                 ps=con.prepareStatment("update status_bits correspondind to the same date,field and subcode");

                 ps.executeUpdate();
           }

     }
```

**Now i presume you understand from the program that i want to update status_bits in the table based on different dates and periods where the bit operation is common**......Now i really know that these method is hammering lots of queries and seriously affecting mysql performance...So plz help me by providing a much alternate idea to this.......there are around 1000 records to update.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you want the 5th position of the status_bits string set to a particular value for a given (date,period,subcode), you can avoid the SELECT and perform just an update.

**UPDATED:** to properly handle cases where the existing value in status_bits column is less than 4 characters, we want to ensure we are replacing the 5th character, and not the 2nd character when the existing string is only 1 character long. We can use a CASE expression to do the test. When we have at least 4 characters, we can append our (desired) 5th character after the first four characters. Otherwise, we need to "pad out" the existing string to 4 characters, before we append our (desired) 5th character.  (Previously, the statement only included the expression that worked for existing strings at least 4 characters in length.)

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET status_bits = 
       CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(status_bits >= 4
         THEN CONCAT(LEFT(status_bits,4), ?, SUBSTR(status_bits,6))
         ELSE CONCAT(RPAD(status_bits,4), ? )
         END
 WHERE `Date` = ? AND period = ? AND subcode = ?
```

(You can add the LIMIT clause if you don't want to update all matching rows, but this isn't needed if you want to update all matching rows. If `(date,period,subcode)` is unique, you will match at most one row.)

It's also possible to set the 5th position of status_bits dependent on other conditions, for example, by adding predicates to the where clause, or a CASE expression (or IF function) in the SET.

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET status_bits = CONCAT(LEFT(status_bits,4)
                     , IF(SUBSTR(status_bits,1,1 = '1', ?, SUBSTR(status_bits,5,1))
                     , SUBSTR(status_bits,6))
 WHERE `Date` = ? AND period = ? AND subcode = ?
```

is equivalent to:

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET status_bits = CONCAT(LEFT(status_bits,4), ?, SUBSTR(status_bits,6))
 WHERE `Date` = ? AND period = ? AND subcode = ? 
   AND SUBSTR(status_bits,1,1) = '1'
```

This approach will cut in half the number of queries you are running (reduces the number of roundtrips to the database) and avoids you having to return the entire `status_bits` column.

(Unfortunately, the SQL text to replace the 5th character of a varchar column is a bit unwieldy, since MySQL doesn't have the more compact `STUFF` function that is provided by SQL Server.)

---

**Update:** more complex expression required to handle existing status_bits strings that are less than 4 characters in length...)

```
UPDATE tablename
   SET status_bits = 
       CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(status_bits) >= 4
            THEN CONCAT(LEFT(status_bits,4), ? , SUBSTR(status_bits,6))
            ELSE CONCAT(RPAD(status_bits,4,' '), ? )
       END
 WHERE `Date` = ? AND period = ? AND subcode = ?
```

NOTE: In that SQL statement, the value of the character to be placed in the 5th position will need to be supplied in two separate positional parameters.

NOTE:

Comment: cool....but do you think...it would affect the performance...coz...it's like we applying string function...rite..??

Comment: No, not a big affect on performance. Your big performance issue is going to be having an available index on `(date,period,subcode)` (or some other suitable index.) The amount of work is really about the same, locating the row, and replacing the status_bits column. It's actually going to be faster to do that on the database side, rather than returning the whole status_bits string and sending it back.

Comment: you mean having a single primary key for date,period and subcode....???...is that so..??

Comment: That doesn't have to be your primary key. For performance, you just want an index with at least some of those columns as the leading index, preferably, the most selective column first. If this combination of columns is UNIQUE, you can create a UNIQUE KEY.

Comment: well..i have made these 3 columns composite primary key and the subcode is referenced to some primary key in a different.....is that good enough...or is it something else you are suggesting.....

Comment: A composite primary key containing those three columns should work just fine. (Typically, I use a surrogate `id` column as a PRIMARY KEY in my entity tables.)  The point is, for a large table, where you are updating a single row, you want an INDEX on those columns referenced in equals predicates, to avoid a full table scan on each execution.

Comment: hey would u mind explaining me the last part.....the strings i m handling are definitelely more than 4.......

Answer (score 1):

You are first reading some data (status_bits) from database and then calling multiple database multiple times based on the number of records retrieved.

Instead why don't you just write one stored procedure which will take the date, period and subcode as parameter and perform the entire logic in the SP itself?

That way you have just 1 DB call.

Comment: Actually... i m selecting the status_bit corresponding to a date, period and subcode(which are composite)....and if i get a value.....i m performing bit operation and updating it to the same row containing that date, period and subcode.....
`If u really think that this can be performed with one query ..!!`
Cud u plz provide an example....because that's what i want..

Comment: What bit operation are you performing? I don't see it in your code?

Comment: `it just replacing a char in a string`...i haven't included coz it's the programming part......the real issue now is now the large number of queries issued....`i really would like to know how this can be accompllishes using minimum no of queries......`!!

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. REPLACE is an SQL fnction which you can use to replace your char in string in SQL code. See http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-replace.html